# Geoserver WMS Time Support - Absolute Interval

Tags: geoserver, wms, time, date

as the title suggests, I am currently working with a wms provided by geoserver 2.8.x, with the focus being put on a time-attribute. The official documentation is really lacking details on how to configure a layer with a date-field in geoserver, especially the "dimensions"-tab.

So the .shp i uploaded onto geoserver comes with two date-fields (begin and end), each containing, you guessed it, a date where a special action has begun and ended. I want my wms to only query features whose begin- and end-field are within a given period, e.g. by submitting `&TIME=2014-03-22/2014-04-01` on getmap i want it to return features that lie completely within these boundaries. 
However, geoserver returns any value where the given time period is somewhat included.

Does anyone know a way to work around that problem? Or maybe how to configure the layer itself in geoserver?

Comment: That TIME behaviour is pretty much per-spec. A better way might be to use a CQL/ECQL filter: http://docs.geoserver.org/2.8.x/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html#cql-tutorial and http://docs.geoserver.org/2.8.x/en/user/filter/ecql_reference.html#temporal-predicate

Comment: Thank you mate, that really helped a lot! Managed to query just what i needed with cql.

Comment: you probably want to turn that into an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i managed to solve the "problem" using cql. I am using a leaflet script, and by adding

```
cql_filter: 'begin AFTER ' + begin + 'T00:00:00 AND end BEFORE ' + end + 'T00:00:00'
```

to the getMap-Request, with `begin` and `end` containing the start and end of the period i am interested in (formatted like YYYY-MM-DD), i can now query exactly what i wanted before.